# In C# Is there any Datatype To Store the Hexadecimal Value?

Tags: c#

In  C#

I want to Check the value which is in 8 bit Binary format (i.e. 0000000a or 00010ef0) is between the specific range....

for example 
(following is C language code )

```
int temp=5;
if (temp>=0 || temp<10)
    printf("temp is between 0-10");
```

same way i want to check Hexadecimal value is in Given rage or not ....

Comment: In what datatype is the hexadecimal value stored when it's passed in to the code? char*?

Comment: There is no such thing as a hexadecimal value. There are integer values that can be displayed in decimal or hexadecimal format.

Comment: what does it mean checking "hexadecimal"? Hex or dec or binary or wathever is just the *reprentation* of the value.

Comment: i want to just check the given number which is in Hex format is in specific Hex Range...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int temp=0x5;` followed by `if (temp >= 0xa || temp < 0x10ef0)` looks like what you want.

That `||` means OR however, you probably want AND (`&&`).

Basically, prefix with `0x` to tell the compiler you're specifying something in hex.

Answer (score 8):

You may use int family types:

```
int val=0x19;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the string of the hex value to an integer

```
int hexvalue = int.Parse(value.ToString(),System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

and then do your normal test

```
if (hexvalue >=0 || hexvalue <10)
    Console.WriteLine("hexvalue is between 0-10");
```

Answer (score 3):

Except for the "printf" the code you post in C compile with the same effects in C#:

```
 int temp=5;
    if (temp>=0 || temp<10)
        Console.WriteLine("temp is between 0-10");
```

if you need to represent in C# an hexadecimal constant, prefix it with `0x`, as you are used to do in C.